# Google bar chart margin between axis and first colum

Tags: google-visualization

How to increase the space between the axis and the first column in material bar charts ? I tried many things

```
options.chartArea = { left: '8%', top: '8%', width: "70%", height: "70%" };
```

it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there isn't an option to adjust the space you reference

would have to insert a blank row

adjusting the `chartArea` will only *move* the axis and first column,
but they will still be in the same proximity to each other

in addition, the `chartArea` option simply doesn't work on a *Material* chart
along with several others

see following working snippet

a blank row is used to create the space,
you can see the difference `chartArea.left` makes on the *Core* chart,
but as mentioned, the axis would still be in close proximity without the blank row

there is also an option -- `theme: 'Material'` -- for *Core* charts

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['ID', 'Col A'],
      [' ', null],
      ['1000', 4],
      ['1001', 4],
      ['1002', 6]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chartArea: {
        left: 140
      },
      height: 400,
      vAxes: {
        0: {
          format: 'currency',
          title: 'Labor Cost per Invoice'
        }
      },
      width: 600
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

    options.theme = 'material';
    var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
    chart1.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['bar', 'corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>Material Chart</div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div>Core Chart</div>
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps -- also when using _Material_ charts, don't forget to convert the options -- `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options)`